# Cross-platform (Mac/Win) printing framework that meets following requirements

Tags: pdf, cross-platform, http, printing

The platform should meet the following requirements:

1. Ability to request the installed printers and their corresponding paper trays/sources, and send and print a PDF file to one of these printers and paper trays/sources/bins.
2. Ability to send raw commands to a specific printer.
3. Ability to send HTTP requests.
4. Ability to monitor/poll directories and call a function in the background when a change occurs (e.g. a newly deposited file) based on the modification.

Do you know any cross platform frame work that meets these requirements?

Comment: Are you looking for a programing library or some sort of ready-made program to do all those things?

Comment: @Alejandro I am looking for a programm library/framework. I used the framework .NET Maui 7 but encountered many problems when trying to select printers and bins on Mac and also printing on Mac. Therefore I look for other frameworks that fullfil the requirements above